# Leaflet растягивающийся маркер с текстом

Tags: javascript, leafletjs

Использую Leaflet плагин extra-markers
Если добавить marker с описанием icon:

```
    var redMarker = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({

                        icon: 'fa-number',
                        number: point.displayValue,
                        markerColor: TYPES[point.displayType],
                        svg: true
                        });
```

То все Ок. Пока point.displayValue не будет больше двух символов.

У Яндекса есть тип метки islands#greenStretchyIcon - который растягивается в зависимости от контента в iconContent.

Были идеи использовать  или  в качестве custom icon, но не взлетело..

Можно ли сделать метку с растягивающимся text полем внутри на  leaflet ?

Comment: Почему вы не хотите использовать стандартные метки https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark или написать макет самостоятельно https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape ?

Comment: потому что не хочу использовать yandex api =)